# Starting Attributes in Savage World

Tags: savage-worlds

So you start with 5 points to distribute amongst attributes, then if they take 1 Major Hindrance and 2 Minor Hindrances do they get 2 more points to distribute to attributes?

Comment: You have two incompatible tags here — Interface Zero is science fiction, and Savage Worlds Fantasy Companion is, well, fantasy. What are you actually asking about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a distinct possibility.

Assuming that the character generation rules are the same as those found in the Savage Worlds core book: Players receive the five attribute points, and taking a full complement of Hindrances gives you four special points - which may be spent to gain two attribute points.  Players may also spend them for Edges, skills, or additional starting wealth.

After these two increases, Attribute increases are harder to come by, available only once per rank.

Comment: Then if I spend those hindrance points for attributes, do I also get 2 edge?

Comment: No - but you may want to create a new question specifically for that topic.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you start with 5 Attribute points, each of which can be used to increase an Attribute by one level.

You can also take a maximum of one Major (2 points) and two Minor Hindrances (1 point each). This means the maximum number of Hindrance points you can start with is 4. These can be spent on different things:

- 2 points can be used to increase an Attribute
- 2 points can be used to buy an Edge
- 1 point can be used to increase a Skill by one level
- 1 point can be used to increase starting funds by 100%

(Savage Worlds Deluxe Explorers Edition, p. 48)

This means you could take one Major and two Minor Hindrances and use the 4 points you gain to increase two Attributes. Assuming you were human, this would then leave you with just the one Edge though, which you gain from being human. If you wanted a second Edge, you could just increase the one Attribute and spend the other 2 Hindrance points on the second Edge.

Note, this answer is based on the assumption that you are just using the core Savage Worlds rulebook. Some setting books adapt, change or add to character creation rules significantly. If you have a question about a specific published setting you are playing with, then I would advise you to ask that separately.